# TeamCity + CAKE: Displaying VSTest output in project summary

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, cakebuild

I am aware that there is already a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38903165/how-to-display-build-error-messages-in-teamcity-when-using-cake-build-scripts), but I think my problem is sufficiently different to warrant creating a new post.

I use CAKE 0.21.1.0.

As a build step on TeamCity, I am executing `build.ps1`, which in turn invokes `build.cake`. In the `build.cake` script, I have added a task called `RunTests`, which uses the VS Test Runner to execute my unit tests.

Currently, whenever there are failed tests, all I see is `Exit code 1` on the TeamCity main page:

[image]

When I navigate to view the build log itself, I see more details about the failed tests:

[image]

In the screenshot above, I have highlighted the text output that I would like to display on the TeamCity main page as part of the project's summary, instead of `Exit code 1`.

How can I capture the VS Test Runner output, so that I can include it as part of my build script's [interaction with TeamCity](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-ReportingBuildProblems)?

**UPDATE:**

Thank you @mholo65 for [his reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45841284/3559686)! I tried the first approach that he outlined, but unfortunately it did not work for me.

I modified my `build.cake` script to include these lines:

```
VSTest("./**/bin/Release/CakeTest.dll", new VSTestSettings() { Logger = "trx"} );
TeamCity.ImportData("vstest", "./TestResults/*.trx");
```

When running the tests on my TeamCity build agent, this is my working/checkout directory:

[image]

And this is the full path to my results file:

[image]

However, this is still what I see on the TeamCity main page, instead of the VSTest output `Total tests: 5. Passed: 3. Failed: 2. Skipped: 0.`:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You have two options.

1. Have `vstest.console.exe` to output the test results to `trx` format and import that in TeamCity. I.e. set [`VSTestSettings.Logger`](https://www.cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.Tools.VSTest/VSTestSettings/2BC6D4A3) to `"trx"` and then import using [`TeamCity.ImportData("vstest", "TestResults\the_name_of_the_result_file.trx")`](https://www.cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.Build.TeamCity/ITeamCityProvider/6860AADA). The path to the `trx` file **MUST** be relative to the checkout directory see [this](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-ImportingXMLReports) for more information. The caveat here is that it is not possible (unlike `MSTest.exe`) to tell `vstest.console.exe` where to place the `trx` file (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14496613/6287173) for more info).
2. Download and install the custom VSTestLogger on your build agent from [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Visual+Studio+Tests#VisualStudioTests-Customtestlogger) and set [`VSTestSettings.Logger`](https://www.cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.Tools.VSTest/VSTestSettings/2BC6D4A3) to `"TeamCity"`. This option will give you real-time reporting when running Unit Tests.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! I tried your first approach, but unfortunately that did not work for me. I have updated my post to include what steps I took, and what the end-result was. Will you kindly take a look and give me some feedback? Much appreciated!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. You can't create a `FilePath` from a glob pattern, instead you need to do something like this:
`var testResult = GetFiles("./TestResults/*.trx").FirstOrDefault();
TeamCity.ImportData("vstest", "./TestResults/" + testResult.GetFilename());`

Comment: Also, check your TeamCity logs. It should say something like `##teamcity[importData type='vstest' path='TestResults/foobar.trx']` and `Importing data from 'TestResults/foobar.trx' (291.39 KB) with 'vstest' processor`